# Spring Pageable object in get request from React using Axios

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, axios, pageable

I have an endpoint looking like this

`@GetMapping("/page") Page<Event> getEventPage( @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20)     @SortDefault(sort = "createdDateTime", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable)`

How am I supposed to pass the Pageable object from my React frontend using Axios, I got this so far:

```
fetchEvents(pageable) {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/events/page", pageable, this.setupAxiosInterceptors());
}
```

Where `pageable` is the last fetched page. Now it just resorts to the default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do this by adding query parameters to the url. Like `http://localhost:8080/api/events/page?page=1&size=20`

The axios way to do this would be something like this:

```js
const querystring = require('querystring');
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/events/page', querystring.stringify({ page: 1, size: 20 }));
```